# Problems to open jar file

Tags: java, osx-mountain-lion, jar

I use mac with mountain lion and java u update 21. When I try to open the file with a double click, I get the following error: `java  file.jar  could not be launched`, or sometimes not after the double click, nothing happens.

Why is this happening??

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your jar file from the command line (terminal):

java -jar MyJar.jar

This should give you more verbose output about your error.